# Enabling HTTPS on an express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

I'm trying to configure my express server to use HTTPS but I am running into some issues. I followed the documentation to setup my HTTPS server but I am still encountering some errors.

Here's my app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/test/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/test/cert.pem')
};

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

When starting my server I encounter

`https.js:32
      if (process.features.tls_npn && !opts.NPNProtocols) {
                                           ^
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'NPNProtocols' of undefined
        at new Server (https.js:32:40)
        at Object.exports.createServer (https.js:56:10)`

So, I tried to define NPNProtocols within options, but that did not work. Anyone have any pointers here? 
Thank you.

Comment: You need to initialize your `options` object BEFORE you use in in your `.createServer()` line.  Move it above the `createServer()`.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this once, i think you should have certificate in .crt format. and you will require tls module.

```
var sslOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('public/server.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('public/server.crt')
};
tls.createServer(sslOptions, function (cleartextStream) {
    var cleartextRequest = net.connect({
        port: port,
        host: serverStr
    }, function () {
        cleartextStream.pipe(cleartextRequest);
        cleartextRequest.pipe(cleartextStream);
    });
}).listen(443);
```

port is you http port . and sercerStr is you server address.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the issue is not with the extension of the keys, rather the ssl configuration used. Use `https` node module with correct ssl options for `ca, cert, and key` to enable https with express.

```
// server/index.js
const express = require('express');
const fse = require('fs-extra');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');

// path to cert files
const paths = {
  certFile: '/path/to/cert.pem',
  chainFile: '/path/to/fullchain.pem',
  privateFile: '/path/to/privkey.pem',
};

/* Express implementation (ignore) */
const app = express();
app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..')));
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(path.join('index.html'));
});

// setup https
const setupHttps = () => {
  const promises = [
    fse.readFile(paths.chainFile),
    fse.readFile(paths.privateFile),
    fse.readFile(paths.certFile),
  ];

  return Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then(data => {
      const [ chainData, privateData, certData ] = data;
      const options = {
        ca: chainData.toString('utf-8'),
        cert: certData.toString('utf-8'),
        key: privateData.toString('utf-8'),
      };
      return https.createServer(
        options,
        app
      ).listen(443);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

return setupHttps();
```

EDIT: I used [helmetjs](https://helmetjs.github.io/) for better security with http headers.